# How to unescape HTML characters when encoding JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, encoding, escaping

I need a convenient way to unescape HTML characters within string fields when sending out JSON. I thought writing a custom `json.JSONEncoder` would do the trick. My encoder looks like so:

```
import jinja2, json

class EscapingJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, basestring):
            obj = jinja2.Markup(obj).unescape()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

I placed a debug statement within `default` but it never appeared so I'm assuming that the encoder handles the string encoding before it reaches my custom `default` implementation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how are you using this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the encode method since 'default' is not called for string datatypes

```
class EscapingJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, basestring):
            obj = jinja2.Markup(obj).unescape()
        return json.JSONEncoder.encode(self, obj)
```